# The carousel Only displays 2 element over the code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to see all of my items that are cards total number is 6 but I
ended up by seeing only 2 of them in loop please help me to solve this
problem we see total 3 cads at same time on screen and later on it get
replaced by further cards in row.

1. i want to see all of my items that are cards total number is 6 but i ended up by seeing only 2 of them in loop please help me to solve this problem we see total 3 cads at same time on screen and later on it get replaced by further cards in row.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}


/* display 3 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(33.333%);
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-33.333%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.carnext {}


/* card settings */

.card-body {
  text-align: center;
}

.card-title {
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.top-image-card {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  left: 38%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1349px) and (min-width: 978px) {
  .top-image-card {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20%;
    left: 36%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 668px) {
  .top-image-card {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20%;
    left: 28%;
  }
}

.card {
  margin-top: 80px;
}


/*th
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Font Owsome-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4575ad6c94.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Internal CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!--JS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Font Qwsome-->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center my-3">

    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
      <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="col-md-4 test">
              <!--Insidee Here-->
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title 1</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
                <div class="top-image-card">
                  <img src="images/id.png" alt="test-img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-md-4 test">
              <!--Insidee Here-->
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title 2</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
                <div class="top-image-card">
                  <img src="images/id.png" alt="test-img" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-4 test">
            <!--Insidee Here-->
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title 3</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
              <div class="top-image-card">
                <img src="images/id.png" alt="test-img" class="img-responsive">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-4 test">
            <!--Insidee Here-->
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title 4</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
              <div class="top-image-card">
                <img src="images/id.png" alt="test-img" class="img-responsive">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-4 test">
            <!--Insidee Here-->
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title 5 </h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
              <div class="top-image-card">
                <img src="images/id.png" alt="test-img" class="img-responsive">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-4 test">
            <!--Insidee Here-->
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title 6</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
              <div class="top-image-card">
                <img src="images/id.png" alt="test-img" class="img-responsive">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark carnext" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 1000
    })

    $('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function() {
      var minPerSlide = 3;
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```